# Use static methods or methods from initialized objects for OpenGL stuff?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Is it more efficient to use static methods for OpenGL stuff rather than initialized objects?

So, instead of an **object** "Model" which contains data of one model, I have just the ID of the VAO, because I used a static method to load in the model and return the VAO ID. Same thing for shaders: Is it better to have a shader program **object** or just the ID of the shader program (static methods create the shader and return the ID)? Are there any downsides with this way? Is it more efficient, or should I just use objects?

(LWJGL3, Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends. If the methods are doing the same things, then there shouldn't be much of a difference. There would need to be millions of method invocation to make a real significant difference. And then the JIT should kick in anyway1

In general, relying on static methods does three things:

- it creates a hard dependency to the class with the static method
- it kills "polymorphism", you can't just go in and override methods to achieve different outcomes
- it makes testing *your* code considerably harder

So, long story short: you typically lean towards non-static solutions, to avoid all the disadvantages outlined above.